# angular - handle ng click, except when that click becomes a drag

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highlight, drag, angularjs-ng-click

The desired behavior is that a user can click on this object (so it has an `ng-click`) but if the click turns into a drag before mouseup, then the `ng-click` handler is not fired.

Perhaps a way to detect, given the `$event` object which I pass to the handler, whether or not the click was a drag, and have a conditional which checks that in the handler?

(motivation is that the clickable object has text, and I want that text to be able to be highlighted and copied without triggering the click)

using angular version 1.5.6

Comment: You will probably have to use `ng-mousedown`, `ng-mouseup` and `ng-mousemove` comparing the x and y offsets and setting a flag that is checked in the `ng-click` event handler.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can set both  ng-mousedown and ng-mouseup handlers. When ng-mousedown fires you can save coordinates and then calculate the difference with new coordinates inside ng-mouseup event. If the difference is small - it's a click and you can run you ng-click function.

Comment: What about the fact that the mouseup might not occur on the element. Further, you could mousedown on it, then mouseup off it, then mousedown off it, then mouseup on it again, so it's not enough to just set a variable on mousedown and check that variable on mouseup.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I managed this - in my controller I have this:

```
        $scope.dragging = false;
        $scope.mouseIsDown = false;
        $scope.mouseDown = function(event){
            //console.log("mouse down");
            $scope.mouseIsDown = true;
            $scope.dragging = false;
        };
        $scope.mouseUp = function(event){
            //console.log("mouse up");
            $scope.mouseIsDown = false;

            if($scope.dragging){
                //console.log("Must have dragged");
                return false;
            }else{
                //handle single click here, since drag didn't happen
            }
        };
        $scope.mouseMove = function(event){
            //console.log("mouse moved");
            $scope.dragging = true;
        };
```

In my HTML element I have these handles set, although I'm certain this is what Roman meant:

```
        ng-mousedown="mouseDown(event)"
        ng-mouseup  ="mouseUp(event)"
        ng-mousemove="mouseMove(event)"
```